# Jesus Christ PBUH in Quran

Tags: quran, prophet-isa

> (5:117) I said not to them except what You commanded me - to worship Allah , my Lord and your Lord. And I was a witness over them as long as I was among them; but when You took me up, You were the Observer over them, and You are, over all things, Witness.

My question is, did Prophet Jesus PBUH clarify that he is not divine and not to be worshiped? If not why not? Did he clarify about his second coming?

Comment: what is the question here. Can you please clarify?

Comment: The question is, why did Prophet Jesus PBUH did not mentioned that he was again sent by Allah to clarify the people who had taken him as God, just before Judgement Day? After all, it was the most relevant thing to say in response to Allah's question

Comment: Allah's question ? .. about what ?

Comment: Please read the complete passage. The question is mentioned on previous verse (http://quran.com/5/116)

Comment: Then you'd have known the answer. Or maybe not, if you're not used to the language used. When he replied with "Exalted are You! It was not for me to say that to which I have no right.", it implies that he denied his own divinity.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, whether he did or did not, does that matter in this context? The question Allah is asking is whether Issa told the people to worship him, and obviously Issa said, (paraphrasing) "No, I did not! How can I say such a thing which I have no right to? You know what is within me, for you are the one who knows what is hidden." Furthermore, in verse 117, Issa is talking about when he was sent as a prophet to the people, or before he was raised up. Issa said that he never said that, and only said what Allah ordered him to say.  Then in verse 118, Issa said, (paraphrasing) "If you punish them they are your slaves..." until the end of the verse.

According to [Sunnan Abi Dawood](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/39/34):

> The Prophet (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam) said: There is no prophet
>   between me and him, that is, Jesus (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam). He
>   will descent (to the earth). When you see him, recognise him: a man of
>   medium height, reddish fair, wearing two light yellow garments,
>   looking as if drops were falling down from his head though it will not
>   be wet. He will fight the people for the cause of Islam. He will break
>   the cross, kill swine, and abolish jizyah. Allah will perish all
>   religions except Islam. He will destroy the Antichrist and will live
>   on the earth for forty years and then he will die. The Muslims will
>   pray over him.

Comment: I think that if he had said something like... I was sent by You not long ago to "break the cross", it would have been very much in context, and an important evidence against his allegation.... Don't you think so?

Comment: @goto Well, there are several millions of Christians whom had died (before Jesus' second coming) believing Jesus is God, no? So the question is in order.

Comment: I think the tricky part is not the question but answer. Jesus is claiming not to be aware of what Christians did after he was raised. 'Breaking the cross' implies that he did become aware of it after his second coming.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus mentions his ministry, he being taken up and claims that he has not been witnessing their deeds henceforth. This verse fits in possibly two situations:

1. Jesus passed away after the second coming. People 'took him and his mother as deities besides Allah' again. This makes the question and answer relevant to his second 'ministry'.
2. Jesus was taken up after the first coming. People 'took him and his mother as deities besides Allah'. He didn't return. Otherwise, he wouldn't have said: "And I was a witness over them as long as I was among them; but when You took me up, You were the Observer over them" because he *was* **witness over them** after being taken up. May be we can resolve it if 'them' is taken to be the direct addressees instead of all the Christians.